# wap dialogs deprecated on july 2012

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've just tried the Facebook C# SDK v6.0.16 from earlier this week in a WP7.1 (Mango) app.

The goal is to post a photo on the wall of a user through a facebook app, so I started to implement login to get an access token.
Bad surprise, I can't get a combination that works fine:

- using the desktop page give a very small display on the phone screen
- using the mobile page is fine, however gives the following error after login is successful:

"An error occurred with YOURAPP. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 11
API Error Description: This method is deprecated
Eror Message: Display=wap dialogs have been deprecated. Yo can temporarily enable them by disabling the "july_2012" migration. They will stop working permanntly on July, 2012."

The code I use is:

```
    private Uri GenerateLoginUrl(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string,object>();

        parameters["client_id"] = appId;
        parameters["mobile"] = true;
        parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters["response_type"] = "token";
        parameters["display"] = "touch";
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
            parameters["scope"] = extendedPermissions;

       return fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }
```

and the generated urlLogin is m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?etcetcetc, from the SDK itself.

It looks to me that the SDK itself breaks with the deprecation of the API, or that I am missing something.

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The C# SDK is no longer supported by Facebook, so FB will not fix issues in it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough just to change the **display** parameter to **page**

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters["client_id"] = appId;
parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
parameters["response_type"] = "token"; 
parameters["display"] = "page";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extendedPermissions))
{  
    parameters["scope"] = extendedPermissions; 
}
return _fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
```