# How to auto enlarge the content or zoom downloaded by WebBrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-7

This code will show the webpage and it looks small in webbrowser control. Do a double tap on it, it will enlarge the webpage. So, how to make the webpage auto enlarge or zoom without double tap on it when it contains only a single image? Thanks

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(strWebPageUrl);
```

----- Update

it is still not working

```
 if (e.Error == null)
 {

  string strHtml = (string)e.Result; // if not using this, the result is the same.

string html = strHtml.Replace(-- Using your code exactly here -- )

webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;

 webBrowser1.NavigateToString(html);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could download the HTML first as a string using WebClient.

After you have the HTML, you can manipulate it and change initial scale

```
string html = e.Result.Replace("</head>", "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=2.0;user-scalable=no;\"/><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" /></head>").Replace("</body>", "<script> document.body.style.zoom = 1.8; window.scrollTo(680,1000) </script></body>");
```

Then navigate to string:

```
webBrowser1.NavigateToString(html);
```

Answered thanks to [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341795/wap-dialogs-deprecated-on-july-2012) at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. I use HtmlAgilityPack to get the specific Image element. So, it is ok to first replace using your code then Use the HAP. Will report the test result. Thanks

Comment: Just tested use webclient to fetch the html and later use your method as above to change the e.Result.  The result: same as before. I need to tap to enlarge the webpage inside WebBrowser ctrl.